# How to select the SUM of the multiplication of two different table fields specifying the value of other two fields?

Tags: mysql

Based on this table schema:

```
products

+----+------+-------+--------+--------------+-------+-------+------+-------+
| Id | Name | Price | Detail | Product_type | Image | Color | Size | Stock |
+----+------+-------+--------+--------------+-------+-------+------+-------+

order_details

+----+------------+--------+------+-------+----------+
| Id | Product_id | Amount | Size | Color | Order_id |
+----+------------+--------+------+-------+----------+

orders

+----+-----------+------------+----------+
| Id | Client_id | Date_start | Date_end |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
```

How can I select the `SUM()` (if this function it's even necessary) of `products.Price * order_details.Amount` specifying the client and the order id?

I've tried with this query, among others:

```
SELECT SUM((SELECT pr.Price FROM products pr WHERE pr.Id = od.Product_id) * od.Amount) AS Total 
FROM order_details od
WHERE (SELECT o.Client_id FROM orders o WHERE o.Id = $order) = $client
```

But it's returning a wrong result and I can't figure out how to do it. Also please note I want to use subqueries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dno't use a subselect, use a join:

```
SELECT orders.Id, SUM(products.Price * order_details.amount)
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN orders_details ON orders.Id = order_details.Order_id
LEFT JOIN products ON products.Id = order_details.Product_id
GROUP By orders.Clien_id, orders_details.Product_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is returning a set of two rows where the second one is like this: `Id = 1 | Total = NULL`.
And how could I specify the order id and the client in this query? Sorry im kinda new to this.